# Backface-visibility IS not working in my css code

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to design a login page where I designed a cover to flip when we shift from login page to sign-up page...everything works well except the backface-visibility of the images and text in the cover.

I've tried a lot of changes in the code but I'm not able to find a solution.

Thanks for any help that you can give

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
         <input type="checkbox" id="flip">
            <div class="cover">
                <div class="front">
                    <img src="img.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <span class="text-1">XYZ</span>
                        <span class="text-2">Where your dreams come true</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="back">
                    <img class= "backimg" src="backimg.png" alt="">
                    <div class="text">
                        <span class="text-1">Some Random <br> texts for you</span>
                        <span class="text-2">Let's get started</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
          <form action="#">
             <div class="form-content">
                  <div class="login-form">
                        <div class="title">Login</div>
                        <div class="input-boxes">
                            <div class="input-box">
                               <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-boxes">
                            <div class="input-box">
                                <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                 <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="text"><a href="#">Forgot password?</a></div>
                        
                            <div class="button"> 
                                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                            </div>
                            <div class="text login-text">Don't have an account? <label for="flip">Signup now</label></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="signup-form">
                         <div class="title">Sign Up</div>
                         <div class="input-boxes">
                             <div class="input-box">
                                  <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                              </div>
                         </div>
                          <div class="input-boxes">
                              <div class="input-box">
                                  <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
                                  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                           <div class="input-boxes">
                               <div class="input-box">
                                   <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                                   <input type="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
                                </div>
                                
                                <div class="button">
                                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                                </div>
                                <div class="text sign-up-text">Already have an account? <label for="flip">Login now</label></div>
                           </div>
                 </div>
                      
            </form>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-image: url('background.png');
    background-color: rgb(33, 63, 199);
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;  
    padding: 30px;
    
}

.container{
position: relative;
height: 85%;
max-width: 850px;
width: 100%;
background: #ffffff;
padding: 40px 30px;
box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
perspective: 2800px;
}

.container .cover{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 98;
    transform-origin: left;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.container #flip:checked ~ .cover{
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
 

.container .cover::before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(12, 30, 104);
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 100;
    
}

.container .cover::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgb(12, 30, 104);
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 100;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
 
}



.container .cover .front img{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 12; 
   
    
}

.container .cover .back .backimg{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    z-index: 12; 
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    
}



.container .cover .text{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.cover .text .text-1,
.cover .text .text-2 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.cover .back .text .text-1,
.cover .back .text .text-2 {
   transform: rotateY(180deg);
   
}
.cover .text .text-2{
    font-weight: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}


.container form{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:#fff;

}
.container .form-content{
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-content .login-form,
.form-content .signup-form{
    width: calc(100% / 2 - 25px);
    /* background: red; */
}

form .form-content .title{
    position: relative;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #333;
}

form .form-content .title:before{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 3.5px;
    width: 25px;
    background:  rgb(33, 63, 199);

}

form .signup-form .title:before{
    width: 30px;
}

form .form-content .input-boxes{
    margin-top: 25px;
    
}

form .form-content .input-box{
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.form-content input{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    padding: 0 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.form-content  input:focus,
.form-content  input:valid{
    border-color:rgb(33, 63, 199) ;
}
.form-content .input-box i{
    position: absolute;
    color: rgb(33, 63, 199) ;
    font-size: 17px;


}
form .form-content .text{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:#333;
}
form .form-content .text a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
form .form-content .text a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
form .form-content .button{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 25px;
    height: 50px;
}

form .form-content .button input{
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 15px;

}


form .form-content .button input{
    color: #fff;
    background: rgb(33, 63, 199);
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
form .form-content .button input:hover{
    background: rgb(21, 41, 133) ;
}  
form .form-content label{
    color: rgb(21, 41, 133);
    cursor: pointer;
}
form .form-content label:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

form .form-content .login-text,
form .form-content .sign-up-text{
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 35px;
}
.container #flip{
    display: none;
}
 
@media (max-width: 730px){
    .container .cover{
        display: none;
    }
    .form-content .login-form,
    .form-content .signup-form{
    width: 100%;
   
}
.form-content .signup-form{
    display: none;
}

.container #flip:checked ~ form .signup-form{
    display: block;
}

.container #flip:checked ~ form .login-form{
     display: none;
}
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

you want like this, using " transform: scale(-1, 1)" property your can flip your text.
[image]